# store procedure to count number of records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm supposed to:

1. create a stored procedure to count the number of records of a table(`showsite`)
2. run the procedure to display the number of records in the table
   Below are the table structure and its data:

   show_id INT not null,
   name     varchar(20) not null,
   address  varchar(40) not null,
   UNIQUE (show_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (show_id)

   Show_id  Name  Address
   1       Dubbo  23 Wingewarra St, Dubbo
   2       Young   13 Cherry Lane, Young
   3       Castle Hill  Showground Rd, Castle Hill
   4       Royal Easter  PO Box 13, GPO Sydney

My code for **question** one is :( have not created code for question 2 as stuck with 1 and it drives me crazy)

```
DELIMITER//
create procedure site_sp
as
begin
select count(*) from showsite;
end//
DELIMITER;
```

but when I tried to run it in mysql it always returned with syntax error,
can somebody shed some light on it?

Comment: What is the syntax error, and on which line does it occur?

Comment: it retured with this:error 1064 (42000):you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to our MYSQL server version for the right sytax to use near
'delimiter//create procedure site_sp
as 
begin
select count(*) from showsite' at line 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS site_sp //
CREATE PROCEDURE site_sp()
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM showsite;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I prefer `count(1)` over `count(*)`